# How to set start line number for gutter in react-ace-editor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ace-editor

```
 <CodeEditor name='editor'
             mode='python'
             width='100%'
             readOnly={true}
             showGutter={true}
             defaultValue={'def custom_code(input_parameter):'}
             value={'def custom_code(input_parameter):'}/>
```

For the above editor, i need the code line numbers to start from line number 10. Is there any way to do that in react-ace-editor?? Is there any props to set line numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setOptions={{firstLineNumber: 10}}
```

will do the job :)

Comment: Hi, can you give me some link of good documentation on ACE editor , I have to modify the ace editor for some personal use

Comment: I already gone through this but these are not good for understanding the how ACE works but these are good for using ACE, any way thanks